# AWS QuickSIght : Appending multiple files of same schema to each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

My  data is separated in multiple files to keep them easy. Now I wanted to do some analysis on all data using Quicksight. 
All data means same data from a table kept in multiple files for easy accessibility. 
When I am adding new data files one after other to Quicksight it is suggesting me joins (like other table which I don't want).

Please suggest me how can I append the all dataset together in Quicksight.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Facing same issue